# Allowing Linux accounts to log into PostgreSQL db

Tags: linux, linux-networking, postgresql

I have Ubuntu server with several users. I want to allow any of those users to access a PostgreSQL database installed also in that server using their respective Linux usernames and passwords without having to use the SQL CREATE USER/ROLE. Is this possible? What could be needed if those users use LDAP to login into that server?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I don't think there's any way to get postgres to auto-create a postgres account when someone first connects. An alternative solution would be to iterate through your user accounts and pre-create them in postgres.

Comment: LDAP will only work for authenticating _existing_ PostgreSQL users, as set forth in the PostgreSQL documentation, 19.3.8. "LDAP Authentication".

Answer (score 1):

You issue looks as if it could be solved by using a *GSSAPI-based single sign-on*. It's not an easy task to set up a GSSAPI realm, but PostgreSQL supports it when the corresponding database server instance has been built with the GSSAPI option. See the PostgreSQL doc, section *19.3.3. GSSAPI Authentication*, for details.